# How can I invest in ethereum from India?

Tags: ether

Is there a easy way to invest? 
Most online options don't seem to work

Please suggest any trusted working site

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to buy other cryptocurrencies? If so, you can use shapeshift.io to exchange one crypto to another.

Otherwise, I just found ethexindia.com which claims to be a reliable exchange between INR to ETH. I have no experience with exchanging INR.

Also see: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader/comments/6vcpwu/safest_way_to_buying_eth_with_inr/

Comment: ethexindia.com is not accepting new users anymore :(

Comment: Bummer, but perhaps there are other exchanges that allow you to buy cryptos, then you can convert them to other cryptos. If exchanges are this rare/volitile I would suggest buying small amounts and moving your money off quickly to something under your possesion.

Answer (score 1):

If you can BTC you can just trade for ETH.  I think bitfinex.com is an easy to use exchange and dependable.  They will allow anybody with an email to get an account that deals in only crypto.